# Push somebody over the edge

Tags: meaning, phrases, idioms, expressions

From [TheFreeDictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/push+over+the+edge), *pushing somebody over the edge* is defined as:

> If an unpleasant event pushes someone over the edge, it makes them start to behave in a crazy way.

Can *crazy* here be to mean all of the following: non-sensible/stupid, very angry, and mentally ill/insane?

Comment: @Theo- Yes it can.

Comment: Yes, all of the above, and more. The [UP/DOWN metaphor](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Metaphors.pdf) is quite vivid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Pushing somebody over the edge* alludes more to a *loss of control* which might then be manifested via anger, insanity etc. I'm not sure that *stupidity* is necessarily associated with it. But I suppose irrational decisions could well be categorised under *stupidity* ...